# Exporting KML from QGIS with relation (one-to-many) table as popup

Tags: qgis, kml, google-earth, attribute-joins, relates

Here is a challenging one for someone.

I have two tables in QGIS.

Holes (parent) - Which contains the borehole locations.
Strata (child) - which has many rows that contain the strata for each borehole

Although i can see this join in QGIS it would be really useful to be able to export a KML that has each point and a popup that has a table of the strata at each point...

Any idea?
[image: Example of the KML pop up. but rather than the parents attributed data. It produces a table of the child table]

Answer (score 1):

in qgis you can join two tables together. right click on the parent table, click properties, select join on the left side, click on the plus icon, and create the new join. And save layer as kml.

Comment: Thanks im aware of both one-one joins in QGIS and one-many joins using "relations". But i'm trying to get a one to many table to display as my popup in google earth...